# ASP.NET MVC3/4 deployment and webhosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to .net world.
I want to deploy a ASP.NET MVC application in Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition.
What should I do can anyone give me the very beginning step by step example such as:
1. Installing IIS.
2. Installing MS visual studio 2010 express edition(as I use express edition).

etc

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Installing IIS.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998483(v=exchg.65).aspx

> 1. Installing MS visual studio 2010 express edition

Download it as usual from Microsoft's website.

Make sure you install .NET and you should be ready to go, if it hasn't already been installed. Perhaps this article can help you: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Thanks for replay, 
I have gone through the steps you provided me. However, I have: 
1. ASP.NET 4.0(Visual Studio Express 2010 in my server) and I created MVC.
2. The version of IIS I guess is V. 6.
but still when I run the page I get the error:

**bold** You are not authorized to view this page **bold**.

I did googled, however, I could not find any exact solution for it
thanks

Comment: Try to uncheck the "Allow IIS to control password" checkbox and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is now working, can you tell me or provide me any docs that how SQL server interacts with IIS? SORRY I am new in .net.
thank